# subfig captions messed up in IEEEtran class

Tags: subfloats, ieeetran, subcaption, ieee-style

I have following packages enables:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
```

This is because IEEE uses its own caption style. My code for floating double column figure is:

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centerline
\subfloat[Case A]{\label{fig_first_case}\includegraphics[width=3.1in]{Zones_A.jpg}}
\qquad
\subfloat[Case B]{\label{fig_second_case}\includegraphics[width=3.1in]{Zones_B.jpg}}
\caption{This is just an example.}
\label{zones}
\end{figure*}
```

The output however is:

[image]

As can be seen the sub captions are messed up for figure A. How can this be fixed?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a complete and compilable example. If you write for IEEE you should not modify their layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `\centerline`, but using `\centering` instead is probably the better way to go in your case.

Comment: Worked thank you! @<LaRiFaRi> I was working on teh compilable code but the question was answered before that.